# Multivariate gaussian curve fitting

Tags: r, matlab, scikit-learn

The MATLAB website says - **There is a difference between fitting a curve to a set of points, and fitting a probability distribution to a sample of data.**

Is there any method to fit a Gaussian curve(more preferably mixture of Gaussians) to fit data with many dimensions?

For instance, I have data with 4 input variables and one response variable. What I need is a function in R/MATLAB/Python which could fit the data into a Gaussian Curve. Most of the functions I have looked up so far talk about **distribution** and not curve fitting.

```
id var1 var2 var3 var4   Response
1   1.2  3.5 3.4  9.87   2.554
2   3.4  6.7 3.2  5.6    4.3
```

How do I fit this data into a Gaussian curve ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: A mixture of Gaussian... A Gaussian mixture model requires training, but I suppose if you could treat your input as the training. It is a lot more complicated than a simple Gaussian fitting, you are better off using developed tool boxes to do it. Look for it on Mathworks, you will find many.

Comment: @GameOfThrows the newest SVM functions in MATLAB are capable of fitting multidimensional data. You can use Gaussian kernels in those: http://mathworks.com/help/stats/templatesvm.html

Comment: @A.Visser yes, but the OP mentions a mixture of Gaussian, I assumes he might be referring to the Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM), where only a single observation with m Gaussian distribution components (hidden), which is an entirely different question.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Can you please point out any specific tool 'cause I've looked at a lot, for example the fit function in matlab can be used to fit a maximum of 2 dimensional data but mine is 4 dimen, and with the parameters I get from fitting train data, I want to check performance for test data.

Comment: you have 4 input variable and 1 output variable, so assuming that the input variables are independent of each other, you could use the GMM to model your input vs output. The Matlab standard http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/gaussian-mixture-models.html, a simple search of Gaussian Mixture Model matlab code will return many versions written by others. Also to add, curve fitting is essentially estimating the distribution, so having the distribution (mean co-var etc) allows you to easily generate the fitted curve.

Comment: @GameOfThrows But curve fitting and distribution fitting are different. My data is not distributed according to normal distribution but the KPI when plotted against independent vars might look like a Gaussian(bell shaped) curve

Comment: Oh I see, so you are not trying to model it, just trying to do regressions to see if it fits well with a Gaussian mixture relationship. Well, you want a 4 component Gaussian mixture regression. Something like this? http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48367-mixtures-of-experts--using-gaussian-mixture-models-for-the-gate

Comment: I think you need to clarify this question.  Does your output *look* gaussian?  If you're just trying to fit the output data, you can do a 1D gaussian fit, don't bother with the input data.  Otherwise, are you trying to fit the input to independent gaussians?  I'm trying to figure out exactly what you're trying to do here.